# How do I convert multiple JPG images to PNG at once in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, batch

I have a folder that has lot of **JPG** files. Now I want to convert all of them into **PNG** files. I searched on YouTube but didn't understand the methods. Further they weren't efficient as they had to do one by one by creating **action** first. Is there any other way in Photoshop? Like select the folder and select the output folder and desired file type?

For example, I have another software called PhotoScape. This software has this feature named as **Batch** processing. But I want to do it with Photoshop. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? There is no reason in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick. A simple

```
mogrify -format png *.jpg
```

or, if you like uppercase extensions,

```
mogrify -format PNG *.JPG
```

will convert all of the JPG files in a directory (folder) to PNG at one fell swoop.

BTW, expect your PNG files to be 10 times the size of the JPGs if they are photos.

Comment: Good answer. Even though OP seems to want to use Photoshop to make the conversion, this is an efficient, *scriptable* action, and will be a good answer for future searchers who don't have the strict "must use Photoshop" requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the File->Automate and File->Scripts menu options. Perhaps you could create droplet or run image processor, although I don't know if these allow conversion to PNG in particular.

See what [Adobe says about batch processing on Photoshop Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html) web site.

Perhaps I am missing anything, but by converting existing jpegs to png you will have the quality degradation of JPEG and worse compression (assuming we are talking about photographs) of png combined...

Answer (score 1):

At first All the jpeg file select/open the photoshop/Click window menu/Click Action (Alt+F9)/Click create a new action/Make name Jpeg to Png/Click record/Click File menu/Click open/Select Jpeg folder (any file) /Click Save as/Click png folder ;File type: png then ok/In action Click Stop playing/recording(down area in left side)/Click file/Automate/Batch (Action:Jpeg to png; Source: folder,Choose: Jpeg folder,Check in box:Override in action/Suppress the file/Suppress color,Destination:folder,Choose:Select png folder)
Press ok. 
Then the process will begin.

Pls see this video :
[How to convert multiple/batch images with Photoshop CS4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkLeJJA0w8Q)

Comment: Please edit your answer to format it for more readability.